# Unable to run Xamarin Forms project in Visual Studio 2017 Android emulator

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

Getting this error when trying to run one of the Xamarin.Forms navigation samples from GitHub (MasterDetailsPage)

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Consider increasing the value of
>   $(JavaMaximumHeapSize). Java ran out of memory while executing
>   'java.exe -jar "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\lib\dx.jar" --dex
>   --no-strict --output obj\Debug\android\bin \MasterDetailPage\Droid\obj\Debug\android\bin\classes\classes.zip
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v8.0\mono.android.jar"
>   obj\Debug\lp\0\jl\formsviewgroup.jar
>   obj\Debug\lp\10\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\lp\11\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\lp\12\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\lp\13\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\lp\14\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\lp\15\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\lp\16\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\lp\17\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\lp\18\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\lp\19\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\lp\20\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\lp\21\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\lp\3\jl\arch-core-common.jar
>   obj\Debug\lp\4\jl\arch-lifecycle-common.jar
>   obj\Debug\lp\5\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\lp\6\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Debug\lp\8\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\lp\9\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement\8.4.0\embedded\classes.jar'
>   MasterDetailPageNavigation.Droid

I tried setting android:largeHeap to true in the AndroidManifest.xml

But the error didn't go away
I also tried to set the Java Max Heap Size to 1G in the Android Advanced Options under the project properties - the project builds without errors but that's about it, the emulator doesn't launch (or if I have it open nothing happens within it - the app doesn't start)

I read somewhere , that if the emulator doesn't start it means there isn't enough memory for it so it fails silently.  I forget exactly the details.

But I have plenty of free RAM on my machine 12GB in total and between 6 - 8 GB avail, when visual studio is running.

Comment: What emulator are you using? Visual Studio Emulator for Android or Google Emulator?

Comment: @JonDouglas The visual studio emulator

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs while building the app not when running. Open the properties of the Android project and there Android options->Advanced you will find Java Max Heap Size. Using a value of 1G (for one gigabyte) should fix the memory problem.